# Crystal VS 2005 error "A number, currency amount . . . is required here."

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

Can you help me figure out why I get this Crystal Report error? I am using VS 2005. "A number, currency amount, date, time, or date-time is required here ... Error in formula ResetProdCount."

Formula Editor for ResetBin

```
 Dim intPool as Number

 Shared intBins as Number

 Shared intProd as Number

 If intPool <> {CSTM_POOLING_GENERATEPRESIZE.POOLIDX} Then

 intBins = intBins + 0

 End If

 intProd = 0

 intPool = {CSTM_POOLING_GENERATEPRESIZE.POOLIDX}

 Formula = intBins
```

Formula Editor for ResetProdCount

```
 Shared NumberVar intBins := intBins + {CSTM_POOLING_GENERATEPRESIZE.INICQNT};

 Shared NumberVar intProd := 0
```

Formula Editor for IncProdCount

```
 Shared NumberVar intProd := intProd + 1
```

Comment: What's the data type of CSTM_POOLING_GENERATEPRESIZE.INICQNT?

Comment: The data type is System.Int64

Comment: I'm going to create a new formula that does the same thing; then remove the old formula from the report and substitute the new formula and see what happens.